# How To Check If An Object Field Has Changed

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have around few dozens of checkboxes on the page and few other controls but I'm mostly interested to capture if the user have changed the checkbox (meaning if the user checked or unchecked the checkbox). how would I do that?

here is my html

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle"
                checked={isChecked}
                onchange={changeToggle}></lightning-input>
....
....
<lightning-input data-id="toggle10" type="toggle"
                checked={isChecked}
                onchange={changeToggle}></lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
mydataobj = {};

emptyCheck(value) {
    return Object.keys(value).length === 0
      && value.constructor === Object;
}

changeToggle(event) {
    this.mydataobj[event.target.name] = event.target.checked;  
    let isModified = this.emptyCheck(this.mydataobj); // does not work, because it looks for the entire object but I'm looking for the only checkbox if any changed  
    console.log(isModified); 
}
```

Comment: Changed from what? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: what I'm trying to find out is if the checkbox is changed, meaning if the user checked or unchecked the checkbox.

Comment: updated the question as well.

Comment: `changeToggle` will only get initiated when there is a change. What else is needed?

Comment: that's correct but lets assume, when the page loads the user check the checkbox and it will fire the event and initiate the change and added to `mydataobj`   `{ checkbox1__c : true
}` then if the user change the mind and uncheck the checkbox so `mydataobj` will be  `{ checkbox1__c : false
}`, how will I detect if the page is dirty ?

Comment: ok so you want to check if the user has once changed the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you have the original (unedited) values, you can do something like this:

```
const isModified = Object.keys(this.originalData)
  .some(key => this.originalData[key] !== this.mydataobj[key]);
```

If you want actual differences, not just an "isDirty" method, you can compare all the values and return only those that have changed:

```
const updatedValues = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(this.mydataobj)
    .filter(([key, value]) => this.originalData[key] !== value)
);
```

In either case, you do need the original values. Just do that when you load the data:

```
this.originalValues = [...data];
```

Comment: first thanks, here is my test result, page loads user check the checkbox and I verify that `isModified` is `true`, great but user uncheck the same checkbox and `isModified` still returns `true` so technically it should return `false` because I put it back the same state as it was before.

Comment: @NickKahn If written correctly, it shouldn't. Let me write up a demo for you.

Comment: @NickKahn [Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/8y0PZ3u78WNhfWGN4gGw/src/app.js)

Comment: @NickKahn My apologies for comment spam, I just updated the code above if you've been looking at it.

Comment: works great and I'm just using `isModified` to see if the object is dirty or not. thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically crate an attribute on the fly and keep `original value` in that.

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle"
                 checked={isChecked1}
                 onchange={changeToggle} label="isChecked1"></lightning-input>
<lightning-input data-id="toggle10" type="toggle"
                 checked={isChecked2}
                 onchange={changeToggle} label="isChecked2"></lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
renderedCallback() {
    // **NOTE** keep an attribute to run this only once....
    const nodelist = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'); // returns NodeList
    const nodeArray = [...nodelist]; // converts NodeList to Array
    nodeArray.forEach(eachNode => {
        eachNode.setAttribute('data-originalvalue', eachNode.checked)
    });
}
```

Something like this. This extra attribute will always have a track of original value. Then while submitting just check if the original value and the new value matches, if yes its not modified and if not then the value is modified.

Comment: This might not necessarily work if the data is loaded asynchronously though, but it's nice to see a different perspective.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes, it might not work in async data scenario. But if the above code is placed right after data is available in async data load, then it should work.